# sum in multiple sheets with corresponding values in excel

Tags: excel, indexing, sum, match, vlookup

I am new at Excel. I have 3 sheets: Number, Size and Time.
The sheet Number is as below:

| Name | Time |
| --- | --- |
| B1 | 20 |
| B5 | 10 |
| B12 | 40 |
| S1 | 50 |
| S2 | 70 |
| T2 | 80 |

The sheet Size is a contingency table with combined of values from the 1st column of the sheet Number (I am lazy to fill in all the combined but the left cells have the same principe as combined values):

|  | ABC | BHG | XYZ | KLM | RTY | VBN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | B1B12 | B5S1 |  |  |  |  |
| BHG | S2T2 | T2S2 |  |  |  |  |
| XYZ | B1B5B12 | T2S2B5 |  |  |  |  |
| KLM | B1B12S1 | B5B12 |  |  |  |  |
| RTY | T2S2S1 | S1S2 |  |  |  |  |
| VBN | T2T2S1 | S1T2 |  |  |  |  |

Now, I expect to create the third sheet - Time which is similar to the sheet Size but the combined values are replaced by the sum of the corresponding values in the sheet Number. For example:

|  | ABC | BHG | XYZ | KLM | RTY | VBN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 60 | 60 |  |  |  |  |
| BHG | 150 | 150 |  |  |  |  |
| XYZ | 70 | 160 |  |  |  |  |
| KLM | 110 | 50 |  |  |  |  |
| RTY | 200 | 120 |  |  |  |  |
| VBN | 210 | 130 |  |  |  |  |

The combined values of ABC and ABC is : B1 + B12 = 60
All left cells are calculated as the same way.

Does anyone know how to do it in Excel ?

I have tried Vlookup but as a beginner, I do not know where are the errors.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

*Here is one way of doing it, it is assumed that there is no `Excel Constraints` as per the tags posted, formulas used exclusively available for `MS365` users:*

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Size, VLOOKUP($A2,Size!$A$2:$G$7,XMATCH(Time!B$1,Size!$A$1:$G$1),0),
     _SplitAlpha, TEXTSPLIT(_Size,,SEQUENCE(10)-1,1),
     _SplitNum, TEXTSPLIT(_Size,,CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,65)),1),
     IFERROR(SUM(VLOOKUP(_SplitAlpha&_SplitNum,Number!$A$2:$B$7,2,0)),""))
```

---

Comment: Thks for your help. However, it gave me #NAME? 
Do you suggest me how to check it ?

Comment: @Hoang-GiangPham it means those formula(s) don't support your version of `Excel` as is already mentioned formula(s) posted are exclusively for `MS365` users

Comment: Okay. So in this case, do you have an alternatively solution ? Thks in advance

Comment: @Hoang-GiangPham what is your version of `Excel`?

Comment: Microsoft® Excel® 2019 MSO (Version 2402 Build 16.0.17328.20124) 32-bit. This is my exel version

Comment: @Hoang-GiangPham I do not think it will be possible without a delimiter between the names in older versions.

Comment: It gets complicated. sorry!